# Windows 10 keyboard problems with Portuguese

Tags: windows, keyboard, windows-10

Using the virtual keyboard, I cannot insert the (at) symbol or the (pound) symbol.

I'm using a Portuguese (Portugal) QWERTY keyboard.  Neither of these keys work on the physical keyboard, either.

I tried some other keyboard configurations with other languages, and @ and £ work in certain configurations, including the touch keyboard.  It doesn't work on the Portuguese one, but if I switch to English it works.

EDIT: Is works when inserting password on the login page of Windows.

EDIT2: And because we are dealing with Windows, for no reason it started working again... Well.

Comment: So for those two symbols (and only those), nothing happens when you press the key?

Comment: Yes. And its hard to explain but, i tried some other keyboard config with other language and @ and £ work. I also tried in the touch keyboard and nothing in the Portuguese one, but if I switch to English it works. Strange...

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, it works for me. Go to Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\Language\Language options, navigate to input method, "Add an input method", select your keyboard type "QWERTY Portuguese", remove any other if you don't use. I hope it helps.

Regards.